# How is a Brownian motion a collection of random variables

Tags: statistics

In financial mathematics textbooks I have seen it described as a collection of random variables (in the statistics sense of the term random variable), but is that just because at any given moment, there is a subsequent distribution of prices? So every timestep on a moment-by-moment basis independently has a potentially unique probability distribution of future prices?